# Can Lua send extended function Keys? ex F13-F24

Tags: lua

I tried sending F13 with kb.stroke("F13");

Well it doesn't work, works fine with anything F12 and below.

I'm trying to use this in a custom remote in Unified Remote app, so my only workaround for know is using os.start to run an ahk script that does the key sending but it's a very slow approach.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have FFI module available, so you can send anything using WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

```
local ffi = require"ffi"

ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct {
   uintptr_t type;
   uint16_t  wVk;
   uint16_t  wScan;
   uint32_t  dwFlags;
   uint32_t  time;
   uintptr_t dwExtraInfo;
   uint32_t  x[2];
} INP;
int SendInput(int, void*, int);
]]

local inp_t = ffi.typeof"INP[2]"

local function PressAndReleaseKey(vkey)
   local inp = inp_t()
   for j = 0, 1 do
      inp[j].type = 1
      inp[j].wVk = vkey
      inp[j].dwFlags = j * 2
   end
   ffi.C.SendInput(2, inp, ffi.sizeof"INP")
end

PressAndReleaseKey(0x57)  -- W
PressAndReleaseKey(0x7C)  -- F13
```

VKeys:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes